# Build a php array in foreach loop that I can sort

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a foreach loop that goes through to get information related to a photo.

It's basically this

```
foreach($medias as $image) {
  $fullImage = $image->imageHighResolutionUrl;
  $standardRes = $image->imageStandardResolutionUrl;
  $caption = $image->caption;
  $createdTime = date("Y-m-d",$image->createdTime);
  $imageCode = $image->code;
}
```

Now I want to put that data into an array (I'm assuming), so I can sort it by $createdTime then loop through the data to run an "INSERT INTO table" mysql query for each photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can store the data into an array by the following way -

```
        $sl = 0;
        foreach($medias as $image) {

            $data[$sl]['fullImage']   = $image->imageHighResolutionUrl;
            $data[$sl]['standardRes'] = $image->imageStandardResolutionUrl;
            $data[$sl]['caption']     = $image->caption;
            $data[$sl]['createdTime'] = date("Y-m-d",$image->createdTime);
            $data[$sl]['imageCode']   = $image->code;

            $sl++;
        }


        echo print_r($data);
```

Now you can a sort the **$data** variable whatever you want. Then loop through the data and entry into Database.

let me know if you any problem there.